# Vertical scrolling Collection View inside a Scroll View

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have `scrollView` inside which there is an `UIView`, and a Segment Control and below that a `collectionView`.

What I want to happen is when I am scrolling for the first time, the `collectionView` scroll is `disabled` and the whole view scrolls. 
When `scrollView` stops at an offset, then I want the same scroll to be applicable on `collectionView` without lifting the finger.

Here is the image. The contentView is calling a view which is a collectionView:
[image: Here is the image. The contentView is calling a view which is a collectionView]

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "when `scrollView` stops at an offset", given that you have also said "without lifting the finger"?